# Positive integers that are factors of 9800

Tags: combinatorics

The problem reads: *Evaluate the number of positive integers that are factos of 9800.*

The answer claims to be $3*2^2$, but I think is $3^2*4$, because each factor of $9800$ can be obtained from its prime product form $2^3*5^2*7^2$. Thus, each factor is a combination of the possible ways of choosing the exponent for either $2,5$ or $7$.

---

I got this problem from the book Enumerative Comabinatorics, by Charalambides. I think it has several errata in them, do you know any webpage where these errata is reported?

Comment: if $x = p_1^ip_2^jp_3^k,$ then there are $(i+1)(j+1)(k+1)$ factors of $x.$

Comment: He is agreeing with your answer and giving a more general result than just for this specific $n$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully, that's right.

Comment: Actually, I amended my comment.  I had stupidly assumed that the book had the right answer and you had the wrong answer, and had more information to point out your error.  When I saw that you were indeed correct, I simplified my comment to affirm your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

$9800 = 2^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2$ and so there are $(3+1)(2+1)(2+1)=36$ divisors.

Answer (score 1):

Right. The options include $0$, so there are $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 36$ choices:

$1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 14, 20, 25, 28, 35, 40, 49, 50, 56, 70, 98, 100, 140, 175, 196, 200, 245, 280, 350, 392, 490, 700, 980, 1225, 1400, 1960, 2450, 4900, 9800$